# event.preventDefault() on file input doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, input, preventdefault

**HTML**

```
<input id="file-upload" name="files" type="file" multiple="">
```

**JavaScript**

```
if (inputType === "file") {
  console.log(event);
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.files);

  /* do other stuff */
}
```

When I select a file, its name shows next to the input and also it is added to the [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) of the input, so what exactly is `event.preventDefault()` preventing? :/

[image: animated gif showing input]

**Aim (eventually at least)**

Allow users to select files, but stop default behaviour, grab the file(s) and append them to [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) manually and also (this is a nice to have) list the file(s) selected for upload by creating some HTML on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no default action for a input’s change event so calling preventDefault() on the event will have no effect.

**EDIT:**

**The FileList object cannot be modified, so how do you modify a file collection?**

Well, the answer is pretty simple.

1. Declare and initialize the custom FileList array

   `var selectedFiles= [];`
2. In the **onChange** event, append the selected files to that variable:

   ```
   array.forEach(e.target.files, (file) => {
           selectedFiles.push(file);
      });
   ```
3. Append the variable to `FormData` and submit

   ```
   let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#request-for-change-form'));

   // Creates a new request
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("POST", "{your action here}");

   // Append the files to the formdata
   for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
     formData.append("files[]", selectedFiles[i]);
   }

   // Submit the form
   request.send(formData);
   ```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, in the backend, the files aren't coming through: https://imgur.com/a/vfqD6rh. The code is: https://gist.github.com/JwanKhalaf/9e00aa9cdecb580990d13c687be92897

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. See my last step for how to use FormData properly.